# Which correlation analysis to use?

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation

I am investigating some dichotomous criterion variables and some continuous criterion variables to determine if they can predict a dichotomous variable.  I am ok with the regression I need to run on this.  However, I would like to look at the correlation statistics prior to doing this.  ***Can someone shed some light as to which correlation analysis I should perform to do this.***  I do not believe that I can employ Pearson's r since there is not a linear relationship.  But perhaps I am incorrect...it happens often.  But if anyone can set me straight on this I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you in advance to anyone who can assist me with this.  Have a great day...

Answer (score 0):

you can use spearman rho correlation as this on captures the monotonic relationship between the variables other wise you can also look at the confidence intervals for the coefficients as if there is high correlation between the variables then the intervals will be large.

Comment: High correlation does not necessarily make confidence intervals large.